# Swift UI Testing: Failed to install requested application

Tags: ios, swift, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I recorded a UI test case and when I try to run it I get the following message:

```
"Failed to install the requested application. The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined. Ensure that the application's info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier."
```

It appears for both testing on the simulator and device. The application itself can be build and runs completely without problems on simulator and device. UI Tests for other applications on the same machine run as well.

The info.plist of the UI Test target is the default info.plist which was created when I added the UI test target. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The new target had a special character in its name. I created another target without special character and with that it works. This seems to be a bug in Xcode.

Comment: For anyone else with the op's issue, after many hours of searching and attempting to debug I found my `Info.plist` was misnamed `info.plist` which was causing the above error on xcode 10.1